# Mutli-line UILabel truncating to 1 line when using Slide Over on iPad

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, ios9

I have a `UITableView`'s `tableHeaderView` property that contains an `UIImage`, a single-line `UILabel` and then a multi-line `UILabel`. The constraints are setup as follows:

```
self.addConstraints([
    // App icon constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.image, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 8),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.image, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.image, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 128),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.image, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 128),

    // App name label constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.appNameLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.image, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.appNameLabel, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 16),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.appNameLabel, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -16),

    // Description label constrains
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.descriptionLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.appNameLabel, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 8),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.descriptionLabel, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 16),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.descriptionLabel, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -16),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.descriptionLabel, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -8)
    ])
```

This produces the following:

[image: Table header view]

I can rotate the device and the label will resize to the correct size thanks to the following code:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.updateDescriptionLabelPMLW()

    super.layoutSubviews()
}

private func updateDescriptionLabelPMLW() {
    // -32 for the 16 padding on the left and right
    let newValue = self.frame.width - 32

    if self.descriptionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != newValue {
        self.descriptionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = newValue
        self.descriptionLabel.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

Despite this working on iOS 7.0-9.0 (which is only slightly short of a miracle), when I use the [Slide Over -> Split View feature of the iPad Air 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/index.html) (simulator) the label is truncated to a single line when the slid-over app is made in the "split" app, as seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

Note that this only happens in landscape, and can be "fixed" by rotating the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being fixed by updating the `updateDescriptionLabelPMLW` method to:

```
private func updateDescriptionLabelPMLW() {
    /*
    iOS 7
    Tested on:
    - iPad 2 (7.0.6)
    - iPhone 4 (7.1.1)

    iOS 8.1
    Tested on:
    - iPhone 5 (sim)
    - iPad Retina (sim)

    iOS 9
    Tested on:
    - iPhone 6
    - iPad Air 2

    Does not work on iPad Air 2 when sliding in an app (label is truncated)
    */
    // -32 for the 16 padding on the left and right
    let newValue = self.frame.width - 32

    if self.descriptionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != newValue {
        self.descriptionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = newValue
        self.descriptionLabel.sizeToFit()

        // Check for iOS 9 devices in landscape
        // This should also check for iPads (specifically iPad Air 2)
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            if UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation) {
                self.superview?.setNeedsLayout()
                self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It may not be perfect, but it's fixed the bug!